# Universal hash function with probabilty of multiple collisions

Tags: probability, hash-function, random-functions

The problem is:

Consider the universal hash function: $h(x, r) = x_1 r_1 + ... + x_d r_d \mod m$, with $m$ prime, where for an integer  dimension d>0 you break up the key $x=(x_1,x_2, . . .,x_d), 0 \leq x_i < m$ into a sequence. Fix random coefficients $0 \leq r_i < m, i=1, . . .,d$.

Show an example of $m$ different items $x^{(1)}, . . .,x^{(m)}$ such that $P(h(x^{(1)}, r) = ... = h(x^{(m)}, r)) = \frac{1}{m}$. In other words, with probability $\frac{1}{m}$ not only two of these items map to the same bucket but all $m$ of them.

I'm not sure how this would be possible. Since the $h(x, r)$ is a universal hash function, we know $P(h(x,r) = h(y, r)) \leq \frac{1}{m}$. I imagine then that we need a set of $x^{(1)}, ..., x^{(m)}$ that all map to the same bucket. How would I construct such a set and prove the appropriate probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Consider $x^{(i)} = (i,0,0,\ldots,0)$.  Then for what random $r$ do we have that all $x^{(i)}$'s get hashed to the same bucket?

Comment: If $r_1 = 0$, then I imagine these would all map to $0$, correct?

Comment: @dr_seuss, precisely.  And what is the probability that $r_1 = 0$?

Comment: It's $\frac{1}{m}$. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you!